Error reading CPU table when running `apt` inside a chroot environment on Ubuntu server
Following this question, I am trying to set up a chroot environment on my Ubuntu server running on a Raspberry Pi. Here are the steps I followed to create the chroot environment:
mkdir -p myenv
mkdir -p myenv/{bin,lib,usr/bin,etc}

# Bind mount essential directories
mount --bind -o ro /bin "myenv/bin"
mount --bind -o ro /lib "myenv/lib"
mount --bind -o ro /usr/bin "myenv/usr/bin"
mount --bind -o ro /etc "myenv/etc"

I then enter the chroot environment with the following command:
chroot "myenv" /bin/bash

Once inside the chroot, I try to run apt, but I encounter the following error:

E: Error reading the CPU table

I have tried bind-mounting additional directories like /proc, /sys, /dev, and /run as suggested in various forums, to no avail. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
P.S.  I could resolve the above issue by bind mounting the whole usr folder, but then I got the error:

E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)

which I could resolve by manually creating the folders sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial (from here), now I get the error message:
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Sub-process returned an error code
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Output of nslookup ports.ubuntu.com:
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.36
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.39
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::16
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::19

Output of nslookup ports.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8:
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.39
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 185.125.190.36
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::16
Name:   ports.ubuntu.com
Address: 2620:2d:4000:1::19

Output of wget google.com:
--2024-05-28 17:47:57--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 2a00:1450:400e:800::200e, 142.250.179.174
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2a00:1450:400e:800::200e|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2024-05-28 17:47:57--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2a00:1450:400e:803::2004, 142.251.39.100
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:400e:803::2004|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                        [ <=>                                              ]  20.06K  --.-KB/s    in 0.007s

2024-05-28 17:47:57 (2.92 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [20539]


@kos I have already bind-mounted the entire etc folder, and I am not sure if symlinking works with chroot.

@kos I forgot to thank you for your previous comment and kind support. When I run the nslookup ports.ubuntu.com command inside the sandbox, I get this

@kos the nslookup ports.google.com 8.8.8.8 command returns Server: 8.8.8.8 Address: 8.8.8.8#53  ** server can't find ports.google.com: NXDOMAIN and wget google.com returns this.

@kos The nslookup ports.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8 command returns this.

@kos do you think I need to update the tags?

Yeah and I think the title as well, right now it reflects the old problem, it'd be better if both reflected the current issue, I suggest to also remove the unrelated " Error reading the CPU table" part, since that is now solved and only acts as "noise" while reading the question...
